# Cassandra Database Problem 

Tags: cassandra

I am using Cassandra database for large scale application. I am new to using Cassandra database. I have a database schema for a particular keyspace for which I have created  columns using Cassandra Command Line Interface (CLI). Now when I copied dataset in the folder /var/lib/cassandra/data/, I was not able to access the values using the key of a particular column. I am getting message zero rows present. But the files are present. All these files are under extension, XXXX-Data.db, XXXX-Filter.db, XXXX-Index.db. Can anyone tell me how to access the columns for existing datasets.

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve (i.e why you want to move the data files)?

Answer (score 4):

(a) Cassandra doesn't expect you to move its data files around out from underneath it. You'll need to restart if you do any manual surgery like that.

(b) if you didn't also copy the schema definition it will ignore data files for unknown column families.

Comment: Hi, Sorry If I am not clear. I want to replicate existing Cassandra database. I have created database with same column family records. But I want to replicate the records stored in it as well. In Mysql we can use file.sql to dump the database. Do we have similar strategy in cassandra ?

Answer (score 1):

For what you are trying to achieve it may probably be better to export and import your SSTables.

You should have a look at **bin/sstable2json** and **bin/json2sstable**.

Documentation is there (near the end of the page): [Cassandra Operations](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Operations)